Why or how are standardized parts allowed to be manufactured by multiple companies without any sort of IP infringement?
I have noticed that there are some companies that have similar part numbers with the exact same description and the exact same specifications.
Below is an example from the alldatasheets website listing the same device under multiple suppliers:

(Apologies if the picture looks small. You may have to click on it to see it better. It's just a wide picture that can't fit on the webpage.)
How does not raise any red flags on IP infringement? I'm aware that OEMs sometimes require second sources for suppliers, so could this be the reason why multiple suppliers are allowed to manufacture the same thing? Who actually owns the original design? Are there any licensing agreements that allow other suppliers to sell the same thing?

What sort of IP infringement do you think this would fall under, exactly? There isn't a single explanation for "why it's not infringement"; instead, there's an explanation for why it's not copyright infringement, and an explanation for why it's not patent infringement, and an explanation for why it's not trademark infringement, mask work infringement, phonorecord infringement, personality rights infringement, and so on. Out of all of these explanations, which ones are you interested in?

There are no patents on these parts, infact they publish the circuit for these parts so it's well known (and probably why its well copied). You can reverse engineer parts in silicon, and copy circuits. If there is a patent on a specific circuit or process then you can't copy them without risking legal action.

Source: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/89061.pdf

Equipment manufacturers will try very hard to avoid using single-sourced parts, for assured supply. There is therefore an incentive for component manufacturers to cooperate with other suppliers to produce equivalents for each others' parts, so that they will be taken up and used. An then sometimes, a manufacturer will make a part that although it will drop in to replace an xyz, it's just a little bit better than all the other xyz's out there, so hopes to grab the market in that part.
This argument works at the jelly-bean level of op-amps and regulators, it doesn't seem so valid at the high end of FPGAs, CPUs and SoCs. However, if you're making a computer motherboard, it's nice to know that only your CPU supplier could put you out of business by failing to supply, and that your power supply components can be got from multiple sources.
